# How to store 3gp audio file in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am able to record and play audio but I want to store my audio file in sqlite. and here is my code which I used to record audio.

outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
      getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording.3gp";;

```
  myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
  myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
  myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
  myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually want to put the data form the file into the db, rather than just use the db to track the existence of the current file?

Comment: Brother was you able to store the file in Database? I need help

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the file into a blob and then store it in the Sqlite Database.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(outputfile);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer =new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            baos.flush();
            byte[] fileByteArray = baos.toByteArray();



 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("filename", filename);
cv.put("blob", fileByteArray);
yourDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```